# Bootstrap pass td value to modal not showing it in row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Have some data which i present in rows using tr and td as you see below. There are Name, Surname and Age fields. When user click on specific row those data are taken by my java script code and being passed to my modal window. Everything works just fine expect one thing. Besides entioned fields my db table contains also `Id` which i don't want present to user in rows but i need it in modal as well as rest fields for `Url.Action method`. I know that i could simple do that by adding this Id into new td as rest of fields but as i said before i don't want to present that fields to user. How could i then achieve that the way it shoul be done? Below find my code.

```
...
@For Each item In Model.Transports
   Dim currentItem = item
     @<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalTransportDetails">

     <td class="col-lg-1">@item.Name</td>
     <td class="col-lg-1">@item.Surname</td>
     <td class="col-lg-1">@item.Age</td>
...
```

My Java script which is taking data from my tr and placing within modal when user click on row:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModalTransportDetails').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
 $(this).find('#label1').val($(event.relatedTarget).find('td:first-child').text());
 $(this).find('#label2').val($(event.relatedTarget).find('td:nth-child(2)').text());
 $(this).find('#label3').val($(event.relatedTarget).find('td:nth-child(3)').text());
 });
    });
```

Here below is my modal where data is present to user. If you look at bottom of it you will see i am passing .id = 1 - and that's the point i don't know how to transfer this id here but without showing it as rest fields.

```
  <div id="myModalTransportDetails" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Transpot informationr</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="orderDetails">

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-4">LP:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control red-stripe" id="label1">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Status:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control red-stripe" id="label2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-4 text-left">Arrive date:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control red-stripe" id="label3">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">




 <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "TransportGallery", New With { .id = 1} )" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Show pictures
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>


                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-off" data-dismiss="modal"> Close</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**EDIT:**
i upadted tr as you said:

```
   @<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalTransportDetails" data-id="@item.id">
```

then js:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myModalTransportDetails').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
     $(this).find('#label1').val($(event.relatedTarget).find('td:first-child').text());
     $(this).find('#label2').val($(event.relatedTarget).find('td:nth-child(2)').text());
     $(this).find('#label3').val($(event.relatedTarget).find('td:nth-child(3)').text());


       var id = $(event.relatedTarget).data('id');

        var href = $('#details').attr('href'); // currently returns '/TransportGallery/Details/1'
        href = href.slice(0, href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + id;
        $('#details').attr('href', href);



     });
        });
```

how to modify this?:

```
  <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "TransportGallery", New With { .id = 1} )" class="btn btn-primary" id="details">
                    Show pictures
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
```

Comment: You can add the `id` value as a `data-*` attribute of your table row - e.g. `<tr data-id="@item.id" .....>` and access it in your script using `.data('id')`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke i did like you said added:    @<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalTransportDetails" data-id="@item.id"> and then also tried to add like this but seems convention is bad how to correctly write it here?:  <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "TransportGallery", New With { .data('id') } )" class="btn btn-primary">

Comment: No you cannot do it like that. `@Url.Action()` is razor code - its executed on the server before you pass it to the view whereas `var id=$(event.relatedTarget).data('id')` is client side javascript (it does not exist yet). You need to get the value and then update the `href` attribute of your link.

Comment: @Stephan Muecke i am not sure how do do it - i paste: var id = $(event.relatedTarget).data('id') at the end of my current javascript code but how should i point it to  .id = ?

Comment: I would suggest changing the link to just `<a href="#" id="details">....<a>` and handle the click event - `$('#details').click(function() { location.href = '@Url.Action("Details", "TransportGallery")' + '/' + id; });` (where `id` is a global variable you set in your current script using `id=$(event.relatedTarget).data('id');`.

Comment: but if i would stay with url.action can you show me in answer how this should look like i am but mixed :)

Comment: Its more code to do it that way (you need to cancel the default redirect and modify the href attribute), but if you really want to do it that way I will add an answer in about an hour.

Comment: can you give in answer required changes - would appreciate. thx Stephen

Comment: @Stephen Muecke can you give answer and show how to correctly apply it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the `id` of your model as a `data-` attribute of the `<tr>` element

```
<tr data-id="@item.id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalTransportDetails">
    <td class="col-lg-1">@item.Name</td>
    ....
```

and in your script you can retrieve it using

```
var id = $(event.relatedTarget).data('id');
```

You will then need to update the `href` attribute of the link. Give the link a unique `id` (say `id="details"`) and add the following to the script

```
var href = `$('#details').attr('href'); // currently returns '/TransportGallery/Details/1'
href = href.slice(0, href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + id;
$('#details).attr('href', href);
```

This will update the links `href` attribute to `/TransportGallery/Details/##`, where `##` is the id of the model.

Comment: look my main post - EDIT2 - as you can see i changed tr, then i change js and how to modyfi this url.action..?

Comment: The answer I gave assumes you keep the code for `<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "TransportGallery", New With { .id = 1} ) ....... </a>` exactly as it is. All you need to do is add the 4 lines of script I have shown. - the script will update the `href` attribute (replacing the existing `id` with the selected `id`)

Comment: ok i added also id to my href.. but i have some problems when putted your last code at the end of my JS - some convention errors..

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _i added also id to my href_ - You should not be changing your existing `<a href="@Url.Action(...` at all - it need to be have `New With { .id = 1 }` in it otherwise the script wont work. The whole purpose of the last 3 lines of code is to get the `href` value and update it with the new id

Comment: ok think i did it its working please check my EDIT 2 :) is it correct? By the way is it correct way to do it as making it .id = 1 which will be replaced is it correct way (i mean to stay this id = 1?